# Telling Tabulate Area to use custom textual labels for column names?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, land-use, tabulate

I have a land use raster with unique values of 1-8 and the appropriate label names for the land use are defined under the symbology tab.

When I process that raster with the Tabulate Area tool in conjunction with census divisions, the column names of the resulting table are VALUE_1, VALUE_2, ..., VALUE_8. Is there a way to create such a table but with the proper textual labels for each type of land use instead?

Comment: For the result table field names or attributes?

Comment: @artwork21 I meant field names. I don't know what are field "attributes" in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new field that defines the corresponding class name for each value in the attribute table. `Tabulate Area` does not consider the labels defined in the symbology. You should clearly define the classes in the attribute table, then when using [Tabulate Area tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm), you can choose the field that has the land use class names.

[image]

[image]

Please note that if the class name exceeds 10 characters, it will be truncated because the maximum length of a field name is 10 characters:

[image]